Unable to simulate file upload using drag N drop by manipulating DataTransfer API on dragstart
What I want?
I am making a chrome extension which opens a popup where I can see some gif images. I want to be able to fill an <input type="file" /> by dragging and dropping this image.
Issue
This is my current dragstart event listener
img.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
        const filename = `gif_${gifData.id}.gif`;

        e.dataTransfer.clearData();
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        e.dataTransfer.items.add(new File([new Blob([new Uint8Array(gifData.binary)], { type: 'image/gif' })], filename));

        console.log('Dragging:', filename, "Data:", e.dataTransfer.getData('image/gif'));

        // Set drag image
        e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
    });

I tried many possibilities like using setData("image/gif", DATAURI) but none are working. I also have the path to the local file in user machine, the file url like file:///Users/.../file.gif which ideally should work as when I drag a normal local file that is the path
When logging like
function drop(ev) {
    console.log(ev.dataTransfer.files.length);
}

it logs 1 with actual file drag and drop like it should, but from my extension the files is empty and logs 0
What is the solution?
